# Por qué no funciona?

Tags: javascript

No entiendo por qué no funciona este código

```js
var malo = "caca$+";
var dp2 = ["'\'","?","^","$",".","|","(",")","[","]","*","+","-","/","`",'"',"'"];
var bueno = "hola";
var dp = dp2.join(' ');
if(dp.indexOf(malo) != -1) {
  
  console.log("Tiene malos..");
  
}
else {
  
  console.log('nada..');
}

// 

if(dp.indexOf(bueno) != -1) {
  
   console.log("Tiene buenos..");
}
else {
  
  console.log('nada..');
}

var c = ["hola", "caca"];

document.write(dp);
```

Comment: Deberías indicar qué es lo que tratas de hacer y qué resultado esperabas obtener y por qué.

Comment: No te entendí JackNavaRow

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque solo dices que no funciona.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2871/15855)

Answer (score 1):

Si tu problema es quitar todos los caracteres especiales puedes usar una [expresion regular](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp)

```
~`!#$%\^&*+=\-\[\]\\';,/{}|\\":<>\?
```

Tu codigo quedaria de la siguiente forma

```js
var malo = "caca$+";
var bueno = "hola";
var expReg = new RegExp(/[~`!#$%\^&*+=\-\[\]\\';,/{}|\\":<>\?]/);
if(expReg.test(malo)) {
  console.log("malo Tiene malos..");
}else {
  console.log('nada..');
}
if(!expReg.test(bueno)) {
  
   console.log("bueno Tiene buenos..");
}else {
  console.log('nada..');
}
```

Comment: No me dices por qué no funciona